# Is autoregressive model equivalent to linear regression with lagged variables?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

The formula of autoregressive model is

y(t) = beta_0 + beta_1 * y(t-1) + Error

To me it seems the same as linear regression. I used lm function in r it gives this result:
[image]

I also tried package in python.
I used stats models.tsa.ar_model

The result is:
[image]

I checked the residual plot and of the lm model and it seems to be fine. I'm confused about if the models are different? If yes, what's the problem with doing regression with linear regression?

Comment: First of all, have you tried finding out the reason of R and Python differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoregression is a linear model. You can estimate it by OLS, which is what `lm` does. There is no problem in doing that. You can also estimate it using maximum likelihood or other methods, which is what `ar` does (see the option `method = c("yule-walker", "burg", "ols", "mle", "yw")`).

Comment: Got it. Thank you!